# How to load Login Modal in PhantomJS on Mac OSX 10.10.5

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Testing on **Windows 8.1 Pro vs Mac OSX 10.10.5** I'm running a native PhantomJS app and getting a halfway loaded Login screen on Mac, but it works on Windows.  Basically the initial page load works on both systems, but on Mac the javascript that loads resources to open the login modal never seems to run.  I feel like this is a bug in how PhantomJS operates on Mac OSX, but have been turned away on the [PhantomJS github issue tracker](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13696#event-453677535).  How can I get this modal to load?  Also, I do not wish to upgrade to El Capitan at this time, so please don't suggest that :)

#### load.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720
};
page.open('https://www.dubtrack.fm/login', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example1.png');
  }
  // wait 3 seconds for the javascript to run that pops up the login modal
  setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('example2.png');
    phantom.exit();
  },3000);
});
```

#### Run with:

```
phantomjs load.js
```

#### Output:

```
Status: success
```

#### example1.png Windows (initial page load)

[image: example]

#### example2.png Windows (wait 3 seconds for login modal)

[image: example2]

---

#### example1.png Mac (initial page load)

[image: example]

#### example2.png Mac (even waiting 20 seconds, login doesn't load)

[image: example]

Comment: Which *PhantomJS version**s*** do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: This was with PhantomJS 2.0.0 on both systems.  I had installed PhantomJS with Homebrew.  On Windows I just dropped the exe in the directory with load.js.  I also tried downloading the tar for Mac and putting the phantomjs binary in the directory with load.js and unlinking the phantomjs installed by Homebrew, but it just results in a weird output: $ ./phantomjs load.js "Killed: 9"   I did also build out a version of load.js that included ALL events I could capture, and after the initial page load == success on Mac, nothing else happens.  On Windows many more resource req/load occur.

Comment: Here's a log output from MAC: http://pastebin.com/DmQpcnVB and one from WINDOWS: http://pastebin.com/Tqn91wDn

Comment: PhantomJS 2.0.0 has a bug where JavaScript errors are hidden for some reason. Try PhantomJS 1.9.8 to see if there are more useful outputs.